# super raises error "must be type not Jumper" python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I begin with what I think is a new style class:

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self,size):
        self.size=size
```

Then I create a subclass of this, in what appears to be the new style as well:

```
class Alien(Object):
    def __init__(self,damage,*arg,**kwargs):
        self.damage=damage
        super(self,Alien).__init__(*arg,**kwargs)
        self.damage=damage
```

Finally I create one final subclass:

```
class Jumper(Alien):
    def __init__(self,bounceSize,*arg,**kwargs):
        self.bounceSize=bounceSize
        super(self,Jumper).__init__(*arg,**kwargs)
```

From my basic understanding of inheritance, the class Jumper should inherit all the parameters of the Object type and the Alien type, but instead when creating the object:

```
myObj=Jumper(size=10,damage=10,bounceSize=50)
```

I am hit with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/test2", line 15, in <module>
    myObj=Jumper(size=10,damage=25,bounceSize=50)
  File "C:/Python27/test2", line 13, in __init__
    super(self,Jumper).__init__(*arg,**kwargs)
TypeError: must be type, not Jumper
```

When checking every class with the "type()" function I find that they are all of type "type"; which I think indicates that they are of the new class type; which seems to have been the problem with other people.

So what is causing my problem?

Comment: 1. Your traceback doesn't match the code. 2. That should be `super(Jumper, self)...` and `super(Alien, self)...`; the class comes first, the instance is second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have self and the class in the wrong order:

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self,size):
        self.size=size


class Alien(Object):
    def __init__(self, damage, size, *arg, **kwargs):
        super(Alien, self).__init__(size)
        self.damage = damage

class Jumper(Alien):
    def __init__(self, bounceSize, damage, *arg, **kwargs):
        super(Jumper, self).__init__(damage, *arg, **kwargs)
        self.bounceSize = bounceSize
```